# Is comparison of uint8_t values in 64-bit Intel architecture slower than comparison of uint32_t?

Tags: c++, 64-bit

Is comparison of `uint8_t` values in 64-bit Intel architecture slower than comparison of `uint32_t`? In particular, in Visual Studio C++.

Comment: You know you could write a test program and find out.

Comment: I know. I want to know if there is a theoretical explanation.

Comment: The 8-bit comparison instructions are exactly as fast as the 32bit comparison instructions on any x86 implementation I know of. But I'm not familiar enough with MSVC's codegen to say whether it emits sane code in that case.

Comment: Generally, no, but there are too many variables to definitively answer the question. There isn't one 64-bit Intel architecture and the code surrounding the comparison can make a huge difference.

Comment: What comparison? How are your values laid out in memory, and what does the access pattern look like? How many are there? (Total number divisable by 4/8? May or may not matter.) What instruction set is allowed and used? I suggest you make a minimal test program. If you observe something interesting, you can come back and ask about that behavior. Runtime relies on too many factors nowadays to answer blanket questions at a level that low.

Comment: Do a simple test and check the assembly generated by compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine it's too close to call:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

template<class T>
std::vector<T> generate_test_data(std::size_t seed)
{
    auto v = std::vector<T>(20000000);
    std::default_random_engine eng(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist(-127, 127);
    std::generate(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
                  [&eng, &dist] {
                      return dist(eng);
                  });
    return v;
}

auto inc_if_under_zero = [](int count, auto val) {
    return (val < 0) ? count + 1 : count;
};

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    auto seed = rd();
    auto int_data = generate_test_data<std::int32_t>(seed);
    auto byte_data = generate_test_data<std::int8_t>(seed);

    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto less_zero_32 = std::accumulate(std::begin(int_data),
                                        std::end(int_data),
                                        0,
                                        inc_if_under_zero);
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto less_zero_8 = std::accumulate(std::begin(byte_data),
                                       std::end(byte_data),
                                       0,
                                       inc_if_under_zero);

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto int_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1-t0).count();
    auto byte_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();

    std::cout << "totals    : " << less_zero_32 << ", " << less_zero_8 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int time  : " << int_time << "us" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "byte time : " << byte_time << "us" << std::endl;
}
```

results with apple clang, -O3:

```
totals    : 9962877, 9962877
int time  : 6644us
byte time : 6035us
```

*maybe* the byte time is less because we have to traverse less memory.

Answer (score -3):

There is only one way to find out - write a test program and find out.

The x64 architecture instruction set is effectively a complex language which is interpreted at run time into a series of much simpler instructions.  The x64 instruction set is very stable, but those simpler instructions differ from chip to chip.  It is thus not possible to say with any certainty whether the result is slower or not.

In practise, I would be very surprised is there was a measurably difference.

Comment: It's not so much about the chip itself as it is about what kind of assembly code the compiler generates, and how optimized it is for the particular chip.